# How to see all available `man` manuals?

Tags: documentation, manpage

How do I tell `man` to show me a list of all the 'manuals' installed on my Ubuntu 10.10 system?

Also, is there a specific directory where the manual pages are installed?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To see the most **MACHO** man page ever created use `man man` which will show you the man help for men!

To see all the man pages available in Ubuntu use `man -k .`
NOTE - `man -k *` will also work but `man -k .` is not the same as `man -k *` They both show all manuals BUT * will show some additional things or nothing depending if you run * inside an empty directory or inside one that has at least 1 file.

**-k** is equal to `apropos` which searches for all manual pages and their description. the DOT symbol is for ALL in this case. It is the same as `apropos .`

Comment: I always found `man mount` to be a little more **macho**. :)

Comment: Oops.  I goofed on my edit in regards to the DOT's.  But I'm pretty sure it's apropos, not aprobos.

Comment: Thanks.. `man -k *` also works. WHY couldn't "they" just name it `--list` or something. grr.

Answer (score 3):

all installed man pages are usually located in

```
/usr/share/man
```

Comment: More generally, they are in $MANPATH...

Answer (score 3):

If you do:

`whereis man`

You'll get an output like this:

`man: /usr/bin/man /usr/local/man /usr/share/man /usr/share/man/man7/man.7.gz /usr/share/man/man1/man.1.gz`