# Man Page Complete External Documentation pdf or text build

Tags: command-line, gedit, encoding, manpage

Ubuntu 14.04
man Version 2.6.7.1
gedit Version 3.10.4

I'm in the process of putting together a Complete Man Page Documentation, currently as a txt file, hopefully as a pdf eventually once I find a converter with reasonable formatting, with the end goal of being able to make it available to the Community as an alternative, update-able resource(I've certainly seen enough questions about it). The issue I ran into is that the command I'm using to process the man files returns characters outside the encoding of at least gedit(haven't tried with alternative editors, yet). Here is my process so far:

```
alias manGet="sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade;man -a /bin/* > binMan.txt && man -a /sbin/* > sbinMan.txt;cat binMan.txt sbinMan.txt > manAll.txt;gedit manAll.txt"
manGet
```

Once in gedit, the encoding issues seem to crop up near page-breaks, where it will show a fairly long series of non-displayable characters. So, two questions, in essence:

1) How do I update character encoding to display these files, if possible?
2) If not, how do I go about either downloading an encoding that supports them, or filtering them from the file selectively?

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated.

*Note: I downloaded and installed unicode, thinking I might be able to use that to find the appropriate encoding, with no luck( I think I just don't know how to use it yet, personally)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things. Let's start with your approach to capturing all these manpages. Let `man` do that all for you with [`man -k .`](https://askubuntu.com/a/36844/449) — we'll start with a shorter example:

```
$ man -k rmdir
rmdir (1)            - remove empty directories
rmdir (1posix)       - remove directories
rmdir (2)            - delete a directory
rmdir (3posix)       - remove a directory
```

We need to parse that list. We need the command and the section which is wrapped in brackets. We can tell `awk` to split this up for us using its `-F` argument (we just tell it what characters our delimiters are) and as a bonus, to save messing around with Bash variables, we can have `awk` create the next command too.

Before we get there, we need to know what command we want to run. `man` can generate HTML files if `groff` is installed (`sudo apt-get install groff`). This is probably the best possible idea for you right now as it's fairly simple formatting that is preserved. It's also fairly universal these days. We use `-Hcat` to tell it to render HTML to the cat command (it expects a browser). The `1` there is the section (see `man man` for more on those).

```
man -Hcat 1 rmdir
```

So to bring this all back around, let's have awk split up the `man -k` output, create the command and execute it in one little line:

```
man -k . | awk -F '[ ()]' '{print "man -Hcat",$3,$1," > "$1"."$3".html" | "/bin/sh"}'
```

That will create a HTML file for ***every*** man page. It will take a long time to finish so I'd suggest just testing it with the `rmdir` example while so I suggest just starting with `rmdir`:

```
man -k rmdir | awk -F '[ ()]' '{print "man -Hcat",$3,$1," > "$1"."$3".html" | "/bin/sh"}'
```

That gives me 4 HTML files (`rmdir.1.html`, `rmdir.1posix.html`, `rmdir.2.html` and `rmdir.3posix.html`). To turn these into a book I strongly suggest looking at `htmldoc`. This is both a command-line and graphical application. I'd suggest getting used to the graphical version first.

And there you go. All your manpages sorted, with a table of contents (if you want it), with formatting preserved in a nice document output (HTML or PDF).

Comment: Much appreciated, both of you(@Oli and @mmstick). I acknowledge I'm still learning, so is there any clarification either of you could offer on the above syntax? I understand mmstick's submission, but Oli's goes a bit beyond my experience, in particular the nested parentheses, and comma placement.

Comment: The `awk` statement is admittedly a little tough to parse for a beginner. I'm telling it to split each line based on spaces and brackets and then it's forming a command along the lines of: `man -Hcat 1 rmdir > rmdir.1.html` (using the parsed fields from the line) and then shoving that off into a subshell to execute. It's ugly (*really* ugly) but it's also fairly cool :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of serious problems doing it that way. I notice that when I run that, it causes the terminal to spit out tons of errors per second. A better way would be to do it like this:

```
for binary in $(ls /bin); do man -a $binary >> ~/binMan.txt; done
```

However, I think it would be better if you made a file per program, which in that case could be achieved as:

```
for binary in $(ls /bin); do man -a $binary > ~/$binary.txt; done
```